# Cat rubbing face in litter box?

Tags: cats, behavior, toilet-training, defecation, cat-litter

My can often buries his face in the litter before using the box, frequently leaving his forehead covered in dust. He's three years old, and has been doing this since he was a kitten. What can cause a cat to do this? Should I try to stop him? If so, how can I?